# Python Why does Image differ after tobytes() frombytes()?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I dont get why die image differ from each other after this 3 lines of code. In my opinion the images should be identical.

```
from PIL import Image

phone_img = Image.open("img2.png")
phone_img1 = Image.frombytes(phone_img.mode, phone_img.size, phone_img.tobytes())
phone_img1.save("img2_new.png","PNG")



img2.png: http://666kb.com/i/dk4ykapuzs4wc2e4g.png
img2_new.png: http://666kb.com/i/dk4ykz98cg97grxts.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big PIL/Pillow user, but:

- You open your image with `Image.open()`

  - The returned object is of type `Image`
  - It holds more than the pure pixel-data (as you see by using .mode, .size)
- You create a new image by interpreting the **full object** as pixel-data only!

  - The last part should probably something like `frombytes(phone_img.mode, phone_img.size, phone_img.getdata())`
  - Depending on the lib, one should take care of bit-mode too (8bit vs. 16bit for example)